# Avoid adding exception on website if ca-certificate is not installed

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I have created my own ca certificates with openssl. I have four files :

- ca.key (private ca key)
- ca.crt (public ca certificate)
- server.key (private key)
- server.crt (public certificate signed by the ca files)

I use nginx with ssl configuration.

`ssl_certificate server.crt;`
`ssl_certificate_key server.key;`

If I install the ca public certificate on my computer, my browser let me go on the website without adding exception which is good. But if I have not the ca certificate installed on my computer, I have to add exception to pass. I want to avoid adding exception and force user to have the ca certificate installed on their computer.

I configure nginx with hsts (http strict transport security) :

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate ca.crt;
```

Unfortunately I have again the possibility to add an exception to pass.
I'm wondering if it is possible to do this ?

Comment: There is nothing your server can do to force a user to trust it, otherwise scammers would use the same trick. You can use a a CA that the user's browser already trusts (e.g. Lets Encrypt) or ask the user to install your self-signed CA.

Comment: I already use Let's Encrypt but I want to try with custom certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that my certificates doesn't work with chrome  `missing_subjectAltName`. So I fixed it with this [link](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/). And now I have this message with chrome if my ca certificate is not installed on my computer :

> You cannot visit localhost right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

This is exactly what I want. However it doesn't work on firefox et let me the possibility to add an exception.

Why chrome block it and not firefox ? How can I do that on firefox too ?